# m.2 SSD cloned to m.2 nvme won't boot after cloning

Tags: windows

I cloned my 250GB m.2 to a new 2TB nvme m.2, and the cloning went fine, except in Disk Management it says: `Healthy (Basic Data Partition)` unlike my old SSD, which still says `Healthy (Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Basic Data Partition)`

When I go into the UEFI firmware and select the boot order to boot from, Windows' boot manager [NVME 2TB] attempts to boot, then does an automatic repair. I'm wondering how I can get past this.

Comment: For any current Windows, preinstalled or properly user installed, it should be there an ESP (EFI System Partition)

Comment: Yes its there as a EFI system partition but even when booting from this NVME it goes into a system repair. Not sure what to do from that point

Comment: Is disk in GPT format, if not, curious if that'd resolve. Does BIOS show it set to GPT for the boot drive? Is UEFI Boot enabled in BIOS? The 250 drive may have been MBR and with those BIOS configs not enabled. Since it's 2 TB now, these may be required for Windows to see, you can google that for the exact size issues with GPT vs MBR.

Comment: So it is set up as GPT and in bios it does show UEFI as enabled. As for my old drive its a samsung evo 850 and im almost 99% positive it is also GPT format

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience of cloning hard disk many times:

1. Confirm that your UEFI firmware supports name device startup, and confirm that the UEFI firmware supports the disk partition table of the new device (currently 2023 is usually GPT as the mainstream).
2. Use the BCD (Boot Configuration Database) editing utility such as `bcdedit.exe` or BOOTICE to confirm that the **device elements** (like `ApplicationDevice`, `OSDevice`, `SdiDevice`, etc.) in the target disk BCD Store (be careful **don't edit old disk BCD Store**) objects assign to the new partition in nvme device, as shown in the [figure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5nZi.jpg) and unplug the old ssd device and try to boot.
3. *(Optional)* Unplug all hard disks and boot the computer once to let the UEFI firmware refresh the hard disk information, then connect the new nvme device to the computer and try to boot again.

Comment: Ok so before performing this should my New NVME be in the pc and have my older 250 connected to my external usb connector

Comment: The most important thing is not to touch the data on the old hard drive, because the operation can be repeated until it succeeds. By the way, if you have cloned it, you can directly install it on the motherboard and try to check bcd store (step 2).

Comment: Okay Ill try my best to get it to work. Ive never done any work in the BCD before so its gonna be new to me. Most deep ive ever gone into a PC was the BIOS.

Answer (score -1):

Believe it or not this happened to me because my NVME SSD wasn't seated firmly.  I installed an nvme drive into my system for the first time and I didn't have the right screw to make the nvme drive lay flat. So I applied some tape to secure it in position until I got the right screw.

Everything worked fine, the nvme drive booted right after the cloning process was complete.

The next day I got the proper screw and went back in to secure the drive to the board properly and as soon as I did the system refused to boot from the nvme. I tried everything for 2 days including replacing the nvme drive with a new one and nothing worked.  And then I remembered that when I put the nvme drive back in with the screw I hadn't noticed the audible click that I did the first time I installed it.  So back in I went and I noticed that you have to insert that nvme drive at just the right angle to hear the click.

Once I got that accomplished, I screwed everything back together and the system booted from the cloned NVME drive again without any other changes.

The really odd thing about it was the system still recognized the drive but it just couldn't boot from it until it was seated correctly.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: What you describe is a problem caused by a completely unrelated root cause. The problem described by the author has nothing in common with your problem except perhaps the drive wasn't being detected.